# Compare ASCII of Input values to check whether it is Character or Numeric

Tags: c#, winforms, keypress, datagridviewtextboxcell

I need to **check whether user entered a character or numeric digit** in **DataGridViewTextBoxCell**. How to perform this **comparison on the basis of ASCII values** of entered key in **KeyPress Event of DataGridView**.
Any Suggestion ?

Answer (score 2):

There is static functions in the `char` type:

```
var isAlpha = char.IsLetter('a');


var isDigit = char.IsNumber('1');
```

The actual char presses is in the `KeyChar` property of [KeyPressEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.keychar.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the methods available in the char structure http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.aspx

another option would be to build a custom control that inherits from DataGridViewTextBoxCell if you need to do this in more than one place.